# How to modify permission on an existing registry key in Wix Toolset?

Tags: permissions, wix, registry

I have a complex setup project.
One of child MSI's creates RegistryKey for the product.
Another MSI is responsible for setting specific permissions to files/folders/registry keys and values.

When I am trying to set permission for the already existing RegistryKey,

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
             Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp\Settings">
     <util:PermissionEx User="notadminuser" GenericAll="yes" />                  
</RegistryKey>
```

I got an error:

> The RegistryKey element has no id and cannot have its permissions set. If you want to set permissions on a 'placeholder' registry key, force its creation by setting the ForceCreateOnInstall attribute to yes

But I don't want to force the registry key creation, which will overwrite existing values. 
How can I update the permissions for existing registry keys\values?

Comment: Application redesign to write to HKCU/profile is best. Have you tested whether adding `ForceCreateOnInstall` overwrites existing values? Rushed list: for corporate use you can also set ACL via logon scripts, regular scripts, via binaries such as [`subinacl.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/subinacl.html) or group policy (Computer Config > Windows Settings > Security Settings > File System). A terrible option is to launch the application binary elevated by requiring elevation on launch (application manifest). Then no ACL permissioning should be needed. Also: call subinacl.exe from an MSI custom action?

Comment: ForceCreateOnInstall attribute overwrites the existing value. But will try to accomplish this via subinacl.exe. Many thanks.

Comment: Seeing as you are doing the permissioning from another package that is probably the least worst. You would probably need to use an empty registry key / value element to apply permissioning to, perhaps you already do?